# Simple way to Encrypt Password Field in Legacy SQL Server Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, encryption, password-encryption

We have a legacy application that is storing the user's passwords down in the database unencrypted. We've had a fair few customers come onboard now which encrypting this password is a big deal to them (fair enough). Currently it's just a Nvarchar(100) field inside an SQL Server database table.

The situation is that we have multiple client applications accessing this database and validating against this password.

Just wanting to get advice on how we can achieve encryption on this field in the database without having to rewrite all the client applications that read off of it? It's not out of the question to change the client applications but we're trying to get away with this with as little fuss as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Warning: I'm not security expert but I would not store in DB passwords (encrypted or not). Instead I would store the hash code. Within SQL Server, [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ms174415.aspx) function can be used to generate such codes. Think at these hashes as one way encryption. When I would have to check one password, first I would generate the hash code and then I would compare this code with the value from DB.

Comment: Correct to a point. Not sure what exactly [SQL Server HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) does, it appears just to support standard hashes. If it is not salted and iterated it is not sufficient. Simply hashing without salting leaves the hashed passwords open to rainbow table attacks.

Comment: **multiple client applications accessing this database** What kind of applications are they? All .Net?

Comment: what version of SQL Server is it ? 2008 ? 2012 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not do that**, store salted, iterated HMACs of the passwords. Use something like Bcrypt,  password_hash, PBKDF2 or similar.

If the HMAC is not salted and iterated it is not sufficient. Simply hashing without salting leaves the hashed passwords open to rainbow table attacks.

Convert the existing passwords **now**.